# Convert database data to PDF in ANDROID

Tags: android, pdf-generation

I want to build a android app ,which converts some data to pdf file and i need
to save it in my android phone, i have searched for lot of documents but its not 
helping out.
I am trying to use iText but i don't no how to use it for android. 
Please let me know the code.
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already used iText in normal Java, I don't think you will face any difficulty using it in Android. Add the iText jar in the build path.

Following code adds a paragraph to the pdf document.

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4,0,0,10,10);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("Image.pdf"));
        Paragraph p =new Paragraph("This is simple text",new Font(Font.FontFamily.ZAPFDINGBATS,20));
        document.open();
        document.add(p);
        document.close();
```

Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: I tried doing it in android but it is not generating pdf ,i am trying to store in sd card and also it showing error in console [2012-01-20 17:56:36 - pdf] Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: com/itextpdf/text/pdf/fonts/Helvetica-Bold.afm
Origin 1: C:\Documents and Settings\admin\workspace\pdf\itextpdf-5.1.3.jar
Origin 2: C:\Documents and Settings\admin\workspace\pdf\itextpdf-5.1.3-sources.jar

Comment: i got the same problem like this.what to do

Comment: @Nikhil you may have add three or four jar file with iText in to your build path. Some methods are getting duplicate when you are using those set of jar files. The best solution is using **droidText** which is a simpler version on the iText for Android. It has same methods as in iText but contains only the necessary once for Android. It will also reduce your size of the final APK file compare to using iText.